# GetX: lifecycle methods are not called for nested controllers

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a configuration of nested GetX controllers, which represent my data model. They look like this (I shortened the code to show only controllers structure):

```
class AppController extends GetxController {
  final package = PackageController().obs; 
  
  void openPackage() {
  // some code with unzipping, parsing and eventually creating instance of PackageController

  package.value = packageController;
  }
}
```

.

```
class PackageController extends GetxController {
   final rounds = RxList<RoundController>();

 void addRound() {
    rounds.add(RoundController());
  }

  void deleteRound(int index) {
    rounds.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

.

```
class RoundController extends GetxController {
  final themes = RxList<ThemeController>();

  void addTheme() {
    themes.add(ThemeController());
  }

  void deleteTheme(int index) {
    themes.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

It goes deeper, but that's enough for understanding. In my UI widgets I access AppController with `final store = Get.put(AppController());` and through it I have access to any nested controller I need.

Now to the problem: lifecycle methods like `onInit()` are called only for `AppController()` and not for any of the nested ones. So, is there some trick I need to know, or I use GetX in a wrong way, or what?

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle methods are called only if the GetX dependency injection system creates the instances. Therefore you need to create these instances with `Get.put()` or `Get.lazyPut()` like this:

```
    rounds.add(Get.lazyPut(()=>RoundController()));
    themes.add(Get.lazyPut(()=> ThemeController()));
```

**Updated Answer:**

Yeah. `Get.lazyPut()` won't add the controller to the list as it returns `void`.

So you need to actually use `Get.create()` for different instances:

```
    Get.create(()=>RoundController());
    Get.create(()=> ThemeController());
```

And then:

```
    rounds.add(Get.find<RoundController>());
    themes.add(Get.find<ThemeController>());
```

Comment: Sorry, but this actually won't work. `Get.lazyPut` has a return type of `void`, so it doesn't add anything. `Get.put` will add the same instance of the controller every time the function called. And I need different instances of controllers in my `RxList`s. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please check the updated answer and confirm if it works for your case or not.

Comment: @s-m-jahangir, not sure if I can test it soon, but thanks for the attempt anyway 